# How to use `__declare_last__` in SQLAlchemy 1.0?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I used to register sqlalchemy events in the `classmethod` [`__declare_last__`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#declare-last).

My code looked like this:

```
@classmethod
def __declare_last__(cls):
    @event.listens_for(cls, 'after_udpate')
    def receive_after_update(mapper, conn, target):
        ...
```

This worked correctly until I upgraded to SQLAlchemy 1.0, with which this `hook` was not called and my events were thus not registered.

I've read the 1.0 document about `__declare_last__` and discovered nothing related.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching the source code of *SQLAlchemy1.0.4* for `__declare_last__`, I've located the place where both `__declare_last__` and `__declare_first__` is found and registered.

```
 def _setup_declared_events(self):
      if _get_immediate_cls_attr(self.cls, '__declare_last__'):
          @event.listens_for(mapper, "after_configured")
          def after_configured():
              self.cls.__declare_last__()

      if _get_immediate_cls_attr(self.cls, '__declare_first__'):
          @event.listens_for(mapper, "before_configured")
          def before_configured():
              self.cls.__declare_first__()
```

Then I used `pdb` to step through this method and found that `_get_immediate_cls_attr(self.cls, '__declare_last__')` was returning `None` for a class with this hook method inherited.

So I jumped to the definition of `_get_immediate_cls_attr` which contained a docstring that solved my problem:

```
  def _get_immediate_cls_attr(cls, attrname, strict=False):
      """return an attribute of the class that is either present directly
      on the class, e.g. not on a superclass, or is from a superclass but
      this superclass is a mixin, that is, not a descendant of
      the declarative base.

      This is used to detect attributes that indicate something about
      a mapped class independently from any mapped classes that it may
      inherit from.
```

So I just added a `mixin` class, moved `__declare_last__` to it and made the original base class inherit the `mixin`, and now `__declare_last__` finally got called again.